# How can I condense this code in Python?

Tags: python

I have a feeling there is an easy way to make this code function the same, but with less lines of code. This is in python. My current code:

```
for(CheckNum,Product,Bin,Size,Color,Status) in records:
    if CheckNum == 1:
        row_1.append(CheckNum)
        row_1.append(Product)
        row_1.append(Size)
        row_1.append(Color)
        row_1.append(Status)
    elif CheckNum == 2:
        row_2.append(CheckNum)
        row_2.append(Product)
        row_2.append(Size)
        row_2.append(Color)
        row_2.append(Status)
    elif CheckNum == 3:
        row_3.append(CheckNum)
        row_3.append(Product)
        row_3.append(Size)
        row_3.append(Color)
        row_3.append(Status)
    elif CheckNum == 4:
        row_4.append(CheckNum)
        row_4.append(Product)
        row_4.append(Size)
        row_4.append(Color)
        row_4.append(Status)
    elif CheckNum == 5:
        row_5.append(CheckNum)
        row_5.append(Product)
        row_5.append(Size)
        row_5.append(Color)
        row_5.append(Status)
```

Comment: `for record in records: row[record[0]-1] += record` assuming `row` is a list of 5 rows. i.e. `row = [[],[],[],[],[]]`

Comment: Any particular reason you skip `Bin`?

Comment: Thank you!! And I was trying to figure out why things weren't being displayed properly, only to link it to missing the bin. Thanks, haha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rows = {1:row_1, 2:row_2, 3:row_3, 4:row_4, 5:row_5}
for ...:
  rows[CheckNum].append(...)
   ...
```

Comment: Could you also use `extend` instead of `append` to do it in one line as well?

Comment: @sachleen: Yes, you could.

Comment: Little confused, so this method is the same as having: row_1=[] row_2=[] and so on?

Comment: You need to keep your existing `row_*` definitions. Or you can create the larger structure all at once.

Answer (score 1):

As a general design principle, any time you notice yourself naming things like `row_1`, `row_2`, `row_3`, and so on, you might want to think that you should instead have an array, `rows`, that you can then use to refer to by index without having the big `if` tree.

```
for (check_num, product, bin, size, color, status) in records:
    rows[check_num].extend((product, bin, size, color, status))
```

Or as Ignacio Vasquez-Abrams points out, in Python 3 you can compress this even further:

```
for check_num, *rest in records:
    rows[check_num].extend(rest)
```

Note that I've also changed the variable naming to conform with normal Python conventions, which is that local variable names should be all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the aforementioned optimizations you could use `"".join()` instead of appending individually.

```
row_1.append("".join(CheckNum, Product, Size, Color, Status))
```

Additionally, you could use `defaultdict` from `collections`

```py
from collections import defaultdict
rowsDict = defaultdict(list)
for(CheckNum,Product,Bin,Size,Color,Status) in records:
    rowsDict[CheckNum].append("".join((CheckNum,Product,Bin,Size,Color,Status)))
```